# Get Count of IList / ICollection property group by date | Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

How can we get the CASE count on the collection when the collection is not empty/null.
Such as i want to analyze data, Get total number of Users if the user has at-least one item in the Payment IList/ICollection.

The Class Diagram is list this. Single User have multiple Records of payments.
[image: Class Diagram]

**My User Class**

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
        Messages = new HashSet<Message>();
        FileLockResults = new HashSet<FileLockResult>(); 
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }   
    [Required]
    public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { set; get; } 

}
```

**The JSON Database Temp File:**

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "RegisteredDate": "1-JAN-2020",
    "Payments": "null"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "RegisteredDate": "1-JAN-2020",
    "Payments": [
      {
        "Amount" : "150"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "RegisteredDate": "1-JAN-2020",
    "Payments": "null"
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "RegisteredDate": "2-JAN-2020",
    "Payments": "null"
  }
]
```

**Result i need is this :**

```
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Date       | Total User Registered | User with Payments > 0 |
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 1-JAN-2020 |           3           |            1           |
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 2-JAN-2020 |           1           |            0           |
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

**i have Tried this for now:**

```
  var dataset = dbContext.Users.Include(usrr => usrr.Payments) 
              .GroupBy(x => x.RegisteredDate.Date)
              .Select(x => new
              {
                  Total_User_Registered = x.Count(),
                  Date = (DateTime)x.Key,   
                  Premium_Users = x.Count(u=>u.Payments.Count()>0)
              }).ToList();
```

**Issue:** 
Its working fine without Payment ICollection/IList Counting. but  with "Payments Count" when it renders in the ASP NET CORE API with the Payments Icollection, the console just keep scrolling with this same error:

**SELECT [p0].[UserID]
FROM [Payments] AS [p0]
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (640ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']**

Comment: What about `Premium_Users = x.Count(u=>u.Payments.Any())` ?

Comment: i haven't tested it yet.  what does the **any()** returns?

Comment: It's equal to `Count()>0`

Comment: It Still gave me the same issue. @ArmanEbrahimpour